# C 2D arrays of string of unknown length, Crashing when accessing the elements

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c-strings

so I've been running into this error and I cant seem to find an answer for it so far, apologies if this question has been asked before.
Heres the affected code:

```
char **List_Of_Words;
int List_Index=0;

List_Of_Words = malloc(Number_of_Words *sizeof(char*));

//Processed_Word word is a word that has been read from a file, its in a loop.
strcpy(*List_Of_Words[List_Index], Processed_Word);
List_Index++;


//im looping through the array to print each word thats stored there
 for(int i = 0;i < List_Index; i++)
{
printf("%s\n", *List_Of_Words[List_Index]);
}
```

When I debugged with Visual Studio, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01229240 in Wordcount.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000030.
```

So, I'm assuming that my program is trying to access memory that it doesn't have access to. C is a new language for me so I don't really know how to deal with this.

Comment: `List_Of_Words` is a pointer. But you never seem to make it actually *point* anywhere?

Comment: Had forgotten to put the malloc line there

Comment: `List_Of_Words[0]` is uninitialized but you dereference it

Comment: Also you give the wrong type to `printf("%s"`, good compilers warn about this

Comment: Why do you have "*2D*" in the question's title? To me this looks like you try to have a 1D array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of problems with your code.

You're firstly not allocating enough memory. `List_Of_Words` needs to be allocated enough memory for each word, which you're doing just fine. But each `List_Of_Words[]` also needs memory allocated to contain the words too.

Then you're doing this, which is wrong because you're passing in a `char` as the first argument instead of a `char *`

```
strcpy(*List_Of_Words[List_Index], Processed_Word);
```

Fixing this and the previous problem your code should look like

```
List_Of_Words[List_Index]=malloc(strlen(Processed_Word)+1);
strcpy(List_Of_Words[List_Index], Processed_Word);
```

or if available you can use `strdup` which combines the two lines into one

```
List_Of_Words[List_Index]=strdup(Processed_Word);
```

You repeat the over de-referencing problem when printing out the strings too, so it should look like

```
printf("%s\n", List_Of_Words[i]);
```

unless of course you're just printing out the first character in which case you should use the `%c` formatting code.

Comment: allocating the memory before copying the word is not crashing the program anymore but the printf line is still causing problems, it hasnt gone past that..

Comment: Actually, NVM that, it started printing after restarting the compiler but its only printing out NULL instead of each individual words

Comment: Ahhh...I just noticed what else you'd done wrong - you had `List_Index` in there instead of `i`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have defined what List_Of_Words is but forgot to allocate memory to it.

Let r = total number of words you  want to store in List_Of_Words.

The following line of code allocates r chunks of data type char* where each chunk will hold a word.

```
char **List_Of_Words = (char **)malloc(r * sizeof(char *));
```

The following line of code allocates c chunks of data type char where each chunk will hold a character and stores the data in it. Here c is the size of the processed_word to be stored.

```
Inside the loop:
    int c = strlen(processed_word) + 1
    List_Of_Words[i] = (char *)malloc(c * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(List_Of_Words[i], processed_word);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
strcpy(*List_Of_Words[List_Index], Processed_Word);
```

does not allocate memory to the copy, it assumes you already have enough space allocated. If your system has [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), you can use that to allocate and copy the string (however, `strdup` is not portable - it's not in the C standard or the Posix standard).

```
List_Of_Words[List_Index] = strdup(Processed_Word);
```

If you don't have `strdup`, allocate memory before doing `strcpy`.

```
List_of_Words[List_Index] = malloc(strlen(Processed_Word) + 1); // + 1 for the \0 at the end
strcpy(List_Of_Words[List_Index], Processed_Word);
```

Notice also that using subscripts is the same as doing a dereference. `List_of_Words[index]` is a `char*` i.e. it is already the string you want.  `*List_of_Words[index]` is a `char` i.e. it is the first character of the string at `List_of_Words[index]`. Treating a `char` as a pointer can only lead to trouble. You need to drop the `*` prefix from every use of `*List_of_Words[...]` in your code

Answer (score 0):

You say "//Processed_Word word is a word that has been read from a file, its in a loop." - Hope you don't have that List_of_Words malloc inside the loop. I'd expect you to do it outside the loop that reads the words once

Also, I'd expect you to be allocating memory for each entry in the List_of_Words, but you don't seem to be doing it.

A 2D array like the one you try to make is practically a 1D array (the one dimension) that holds references to other 1D arrays (the second dimension). The content cells exist at those other 1D arrays (the arrays of the last dimension if you have multiple ones).